# How do I make VBA code open local CMD rather than one note?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I'm using the following vba to simply click on a button and open a command prompt window, however when I do so, it opens it up in onenote instead of locally. Why is this the default behavior? I was under the impression shell opened it up locally.

```
Private Sub CMD_PW2_Click()

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe"

End Sub
```

The result of the above is that it opens up CMD pointing from onenote and not local C:\

Comment: What does it mean, opens in onenote?

Comment: Apologies, I meant onedrive. So the command line is C:\username\Onedrive\Desktop>

Almost as if it's opening command prompt from a virtual machine. I want it to open up locally but I can't figure out how. I've even tried to search via local path and that doesn't work either.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/155863/52365?

Comment: Went through a few of those, none of them worked. It returned errors almost like my file wasn't on local on my PC. Did a bit of investigating and it looks like my laptop is permanently connected to my onedrive so it's opening the command prompt from there. I don't know how to force it to use my local CMD.

Comment: It is your local CMD - just happens to open with `C:\username\Onedrive\Desktop` as the default path.  What else do you want to see instead of that?

Comment: The problem is when I send this file to a different PC, it does not open CMD from there. By all accounts it should, but it doesn't. I swear all the oddball issues are coming my way. Also the onedrive CMD is not customized like my CMD, which is why I noticed (obviously not a big issue) but the main issue was the fact that the buttons I was creating were not opening on different PCs.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use /k to process the request to change location?

```
  oShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe /k C:", vbNormalFocus
```

The /k switch specifies that cmd should not terminate after dir has finished. You can terminate cmd later

Comment: I wasn't processing requests. I just wanted a button to open CMD from excel to be extra lazy. I wasn't really automating anything. I could definitely automate a lot of it and probably will at a later point but for now I was just trying to open it as local user vs onedrive.

Comment: What requests - just change the drive to C: when you open CMD shell - isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: tried that too, it changed it to the C:\ of the onedrive rather than local. Since I'm a local Admin on my machine, my credentials aren't elevated on onedrive, so some net user commands weren't being completed successfully.

Comment: Hah - weird situation

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to change it to a shortcut. If anyone ever deals with this, here is what I did:

```
Sub OpenFile()

  Dim FileName As Variant
  Dim FolderItem As Object
  Dim FolderPath As Variant
  Dim oFolder As Object
  Dim oShell As Object
  
    FolderPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Admin.ADMINS\Desktop"
    FileName = "Solitaire.lnk"
    
      Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
      Set FolderItem = oShell.Namespace(FolderPath).ParseName(FileName)
    
      FolderItem.Verbs.Item(0).DoIt
    
End Sub
```

This let me define the exact command prompt I wanted to open. I used Environ("UserName") to make it useable on other users' PCs since this shortcut path is global, just changes by user.

Answer (score 0):

or you could do something like:

```vb
Private Sub CMD_PW2_Click()
    ChDrive "C"
    ChDir "C:\"
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "cmd.exe"
End Sub
```

Comment: tried this, it just opens it from the C:\ of onedrive rather than local. I don't know why it's different, my organization has some truly weird rules that I'm navigating.